# ES6 get nested object in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, find

How can i find a single object which is nested deeply in an array?
This is the code which works. But [0] isnt really save when it returns null or an empty array.

```
this.subscription = state.subscriptionsState.subscriptions
    .map(subs => subs.subscriptions.find(sub => sub.id === subscriptionId))[0];
```

Is there a better / nicer way?

edit:
input data:

```
state.subscriptionsState.subscriptions = [
    {
        "name": "name",
        "type": "type",
        "subscriptions": [{
            "id": 123456,
        }]
    }
]
```

Comment: You need to add your input data.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides done.

Comment: `.map()[0]` can be replaced by `.find()`

Comment: @Troopers that doesn't work, then it returns the "parent" subscription. With a `find` instead of `map` i need to return a bool in the "second" `find`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `reduce` you base Array into a 1D Array containing only the subscriptions.

From then on it's a simple `.find()` which returns `undefined` if nothing was found, or the `subscription` if something was found.

```js
'use strict'

const items =[
  {
    "name": "name",
    "type": "type",
    "subscriptions": [{
      "id": 123456,
    }]
  }
]

const result = items
  .reduce((arr, item) => arr.concat(item.subscriptions), [])
  .find(sub => sub.id === 123456)

console.log(result)
```

This should throw no errors if the base Array is empty, or if any 1st level item `subscriptions` `Array` property is empty, it would just return `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to simplify this if you have ES6:

```
const { subscriptionsState: { subscriptions } } = state

this.subscription = subscriptions.find(s => s.id === subscriptionId)
```